# How to set DecimalFilter to EditText which allows the input of negative decimals? (Xamarin.Android)

Tags: filter, xamarin.android, set, negative-number

I have the following `DecimalFilter` class:

```
public class DecimalFilter : Java.Lang.Object, IInputFilter
{
    String regex = "[-+]?[0-9]+((\\.[0-9]{0," + (2 - 1) + "})?)||(\\.)?";
    public DecimalFilter(int digitsAfterZero)
    {
        regex = "[-+]?^[0-9]+(.[0-9]{0," + (digitsAfterZero - 1) + "})?$";
    }

    public Java.Lang.ICharSequence FilterFormatted(Java.Lang.ICharSequence source, int start, int end, ISpanned dest, int dstart, int dend)
    {

        if (System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(dest.ToString(), regex) || dest.ToString().Equals(""))
        {
            return new Java.Lang.String(source.ToString());
        }

        return new Java.Lang.String(string.Empty);
    }
}
```

I set it to my `EditText` like that:

```
discountEditText.SetFilters(new IInputFilter[] { new DecimalFilter(2) });
```

I also set my `EditText` to allow negative decimals in my `.axml` file :

```
<EditText
        .....
        android:inputType="numberDecimal|numberSigned"
        android:id="@+id/discountEditText" />
```

When I type in `EditText` positive number everything works file but when I start typing in `-` `EditText` doesn't allow me to enter nothing else. It stays just `-` in it. How to make it able to recieve also negative decimals with 2 symbols maximum after decimal separator? I set the same filter for another `EditText` too:

```
quantityEditText.SetFilters(new IInputFilter[] { new DecimalFilter(3) });
```

I want that EditText not to be able to be negative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> but when I start typing in - EditText doesn't allow me to enter nothing else.

The reason is that when you enter another number after `-`, the value of `dest` in your `FilterFormatted` is only "-". And in the regular expression, you are using `[0-9]+`. It means it needs at least one number. So it returns false in `IsMatch`. 
When you enter the `-`, the value of `dest` is empty. So the if conditional is true.

For this issue, you could try to add the `source` when you match the string. For example:

```
public class DecimalFilter : Java.Lang.Object, IInputFilter
{        
    public DecimalFilter(int digitsAfterZero)
    {
       String regex = "^[-+]?[0-9]+(.[0-9]{0," + (digitsAfterZero - 1) + "})?$";            
    }

    public Java.Lang.ICharSequence FilterFormatted(Java.Lang.ICharSequence source, int start, int end, ISpanned dest, int dstart, int dend)
    {
        if (System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(dest.ToString()+source, regex) || (dest.ToString()).Equals(""))
        {
            return new Java.Lang.String(source.ToString());
        }
        return new Java.Lang.String(string.Empty);
    }
}
```

> I want that EditText not to be able to be negative.

I think you need to use a new Filter.
For example:

```
public class DecimalFilter2 : Java.Lang.Object, IInputFilter
{        
    public DecimalFilter2(int digitsAfterZero)
    {           
       String regex = "^[^-][0-9]*(.[0-9]{0," + (digitsAfterZero - 1) + "})?$";
    }

    public Java.Lang.ICharSequence FilterFormatted(Java.Lang.ICharSequence source, int start, int end, ISpanned dest, int dstart, int dend)
    {           
        if (System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(dest.ToString()+ source, regex) || (dest.ToString() + source).Equals(""))
        {
            return new Java.Lang.String(source.ToString());
        }
        return new Java.Lang.String(string.Empty);
    }
}
```

Comment: For the first issue I changed the regular expression but doing that now I am not able even to input `-` then I make the regular expression to be like it was before and changed `FilterFormated` method it stays the same I am not able to input  `-`. Then I changed both regular expression and `FilterFormated` method and I am also not able to input `-`

Comment: @ProfileForStack4 Sorry for the mistake. The first solution, it works on my side, I don't know why it can't work on your side. For the second solution, please remove the second source in the `if` conditional. I have modified and tested my answer, please check it.

Comment: Everything is fine now. I just had to put `android:inputType="numberDecimal|numberSigned"` in the `.axml` file for my `EditText`. Thanks